# TableView row duplication with NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nskeyedunarchiver

i am using NSKeyedArchiver to store a mutableArray after i click at the alertView button

```
case 1:
        [self.playlistsNames addObject:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text]];
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.playlistsNames toFile:fullPath]; 
        [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
        break;
```

And in viewDidLoad i put this code

```
NSMutableArray *test = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fullPath];
if (test) {
   NSLog(@"%d",test.count);
    self.playlistsNames = test;
    NSLog(@"%d",self.playlistsNames.count);
}
```

The problem is my tableView rows are the double of the count of the array.
The tableView should show only these

```
Achats
Ajouts récents
Années 90
Les 25 plus écoutés
Meilleur classement
Morceaux récents
Test
```

But every time i add a playlist name it adds all of these and adds the name at last and the count of the array stils the same but the tableView shows the double like that

```
Achats
Ajouts récents
Années 90
Les 25 plus écoutés
Meilleur classement
Morceaux récents
Test
Achats
Ajouts récents
Années 90
Les 25 plus écoutés
Meilleur classement
Morceaux récents
Test
another one
```

and when i print the count of the array it only says 7.
I really need your help and i home i was clear.

Comment: You need to show you table view data source methods.

Comment: You add to your `NSMutableArray self.playlistsNames` twice data. first in switch case second in viewDidLoad.

Comment: the array gets archived the first time in the case statement.